# How can you distort an image on iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Is there a way in iOS to distort an image layer in the middle like in the next pictures?

Original:

[image: Original image]

Distorted:

[image: Distorted image]

Comment: Maybe you want [UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]?

Comment: I don't see how resizableImageWithCapInsets can help to achieve such transformation. My idea is to be able to stretch the image (bracket) at runtime to get the most suitable position.

Comment: Then why don't you simply set its frame property?

Comment: if you change frame - it will scale the image proportionally. But I want to stretch only the middle of the image to bottom, when the left and right side of the image are fixed.

Comment: That's what the method I proposed earlier is for.